# Using Watchdog to reboot in case of overheat

Tags: raspbian, watchdog

Is it possible to use Watchdog to reboot the Raspberry Pi in case of overheating?
I tried making Watchdog read the temperature from /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp but so far no such luck.

Can this be done by software alone? Or would I need an external temperature sensor?

Comment: it's very unlikely you could overheat RPi without an extensive help of bunsen burner or an acetylene torch =)

Comment: Eheh! Well, mine is running at about 70ºC and I'd like to make it reboot in case it reaches 80ºC

Comment: i wonder what does it do to get this warm? bitcoins? protein folding? SETI@Home?

Comment: Omxplayer on loop and a hot environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think temperature-device option should be used in watchdog config file for Raspbian (8.0) instead of temperature-sensor. There is an old watchdog version which supports temperature-device option version only.
See: http://www.sat.dundee.ac.uk/psc/watchdog/watchdog-configure.html#Temperature_Sensors

My `/etc/watchdog.conf` file - temperature part

```
temperature-sensor = /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
temperature-device = /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
max-temperature        = 80
```

Answer (score 3):

The latest Raspbian has the **GPU** temperature output at this command

```
/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```

and has a result of...

```
temp=49.2'C
```

But the system also has the **CPU** temp- I am not sure if they are different sensors or the same but they output slightly different values.

```
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

Install watchdog

```
sudo apt-get install watchdog
```

Uncomment the following line in /etc/watchdog.conf

```
watchdog-device = /dev/watchdog
```

In the watchdog configuration file add the following line for temperate sensor

```
temperature-sensor = /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

Edit /etc/modules

```
sudo editor /etc/modules
```

And add the following:

```
# hardware watchdog
bcm2708_wdog
```

To load the watchdog you use these command

```
sudo modprobe bcm2708_wdog 
sudo nano /etc/modules (add line “bcm2708_wdog”)
```

In the configuration file you set programs for the watchdog too

Comment: Watchdog is up and running, but it won't reboot when a specific temperature (defined in /etc/watchdog.conf) is reached. Do I need to uncomment the temperature-device line as well? What do I put in there?

Comment: I think you need to set the sensor to `temperature-sensor = /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` - In SSH just put in the command `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` and let me know what it is. It might be in thousands ... not sure.

Comment: It's in the thousands, but watchdog isn't looking doing anything. I've tried settings the temperature threshold first to 59 and then 59000. I restarted the watchdog service, but it didn't reboot although the temperature's currently at 62ºC.